# Limit of Ratio of Two Products Involving Primes Mod 4

Tags: analytic-number-theory, infinite-product

Over the past few months, I have been studying a few number theory topics (my main area of interest is operator theory) which naturally led me to the near-square prime problem. I came up with the following question while I was reading articles/books on Hardy-Littlewood conjecture.

What is the limit of the two products involving prime numbers modulo 4? $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\prod_{p \leq x \\ p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)}{\prod_{p \leq x \\ p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)}$$

Any idea or reference will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Both products diverge to $0$ as written; but if you truncate them simultaneously at $p\le x$, then their ratio will converge to some positive real number.

Comment: I edited the question as a limit question. Do you have any idea how to estimate the limit? It appears that the limit should be a positive number less than 1.

Comment: This should be related to Dirichlet's theorem about primes in arithmetic progressions. In any case $(1-1/p)$ is about  $e^{-1/p}$ so the product is roughly equal to $e$ raised to the power of negative sum and such sums have known approximate values

Comment: Can you say something about the problem which resulted in this question?

Comment: Or your motivation that led you to this question??

Comment: Over the past few months, I have been studying a few number theory topics (my main area of interest is operator theory) which naturally led me to the near-square prime problem. I came up with the question while I was reading articles/books on Hardy-Littlewood conjecture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Landau-Ramanujan constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Landau-RamanujanConstant.html) has an expression
$$
K = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\prod_{p\equiv 3(4)}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)^{-1/2}.
$$
Your limit can be written in terms of this constant:
$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\prod_{\substack{p\leq x\\p\equiv 1}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\prod_{\substack{p\leq x\\p\equiv 3}}\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)}{\prod_{\substack{p\leq x\\p\equiv 3}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\prod_{\substack{p\leq x\\p\equiv 3}}\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)}&=\frac{\prod_p \left(1-\frac{\chi(p)}{p}\right)}{\prod_{p\equiv 3}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)}\\
&=2L(1,\chi)^{-1}K^2=\frac{8 K^2}{\pi},
\end{align*}
$$
where $\chi$ is the non-trivial Dirichlet character mod 4.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input! It answers a few other questions I have as well.